# Relation between Opensolaris source and Solaris releases

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

The source code available for OpenSolaris is very useful for finding out about the internals of Solaris (together with dtrace and mdb). However, as far as I know there is no way of finding out exactly how the OpenSolaris source code relates to the binaries released as formal update releases of Solaris. I.e. which versions of the source files were compiled to form for example Solaris 10 Update 6 (10/08)?

You may draw some conclusions by looking at change dates, the history comments and bug tickets. And I know that there isn't a 1:1 relation between OpenSolaris and Solaris. But are there any better ways that I havent thought of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not any better ways of that I can think of, to correlate OpenSolaris sources with Solaris 10 binaries.  The source tree for Solaris 10 is a separate branch, and features and bug fixes and sometimes back-ported to from the OpenSolaris branch to the Solaris 10 branch.

It will be helpful for you to consider the different consolidations within Solaris.  For example, if OpenSolaris has Gnome X.Y and Solaris 10 has Gnome X.Y, then the sources and binaries for Gnome components will be identical.  If you are only concerned with the OS/Net part of Solaris and OpenSolaris, then the code is only loosely correlated in general.